# Is it efficient to store a chat log using an array in mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, chat

I am creating a chat application in Ruby on Rails and am trying to store messages in an array using Mongodb and mongoid. I have a model called Chat and it contains an array field called chatlog. Is there a better way to store chat history in Mongodb using rails?

Comment: What are you going to do with long running chats, that grow past document size limit?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to account for that. But looks like making a table for messages would be the best option

Answer (score 1):

it will be better to create a chat/message table and store messages in that table.
you can take benefits of mongodb sharding and scaling by doing that.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
end

class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :body
  referenced_in :user
end
```

see the link below to see how mongodb helps you support high volume data.

your models can be like following:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/

Comment: Yes, this is much better than storing an array. :)

Comment: How do I create a table in mongodb within ruby on rails. Would this table be inside my current Chat model? I am using a Chat model to separate the chat logs for each chatroom @sergio

Comment: @user5213476: how did you create a "table" for chat model? Exactly the same way.

Comment: I'm using Mongoid, so I was able to declare an array field directly in the Chat model. I guess I'm not understanding how this is different from your suggestion. @SergioTulentsev

Comment: I think you can rethink your models. you can map user to a chatroom, and message to user. that will be more natural.

Comment: The reason I am storing the messages in an array is so that I can list the messages easily in order whenever  a user enters the chatroom to see the previous message history @khanmizan

Comment: @user5213476: that's not good enough reason. You can just as easily show sorted data if messages are in their own separate model. Also, reply to my comment on the question.

Comment: if you are using rails active record and Mongoid that modeling is very easy. just add a message class and add "referenced_in: user" field on that class

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, you're suggestion is to simply create a new Message object whenever a user enters a new message into the chat and simply save that object to the database? When I run the query, Messages.all, will the database return the message objects in the order that they were created? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: to show latest messages quickly, you can push latest messages into redis as sorted set. and permanently store all message in mongodb.

Comment: My message model contains a belongs_to :chatroom and belongs_to :user.  I was wondering if these are necessary if I simply store fields called chatroom_name and user_name in the Message model and then use these fields to query for the corresponding message. i.e: Message.where(chatroom_name => 'room1'). I am not querying for the messages using the chatroom or user id. @khanmizan

Comment: It will not be a good choice, say you want to change a chatroom name after created, then all messages associated with that chatroom will be gone. you may need to add other attributes in the chatroom field as well.

Comment: Ok. But assuming that the chatrooms will never be deleted once users start using it, is the belongs_to necessary. I will never query messages through chatroom_ids which are integers. I will only query messages through the names of their corresponding chatrooms. @khanmizan

Comment: adding the chatroom_name directly will not add any extra value, but if you create a different chatroom model and relate this with message, you will have freedom in future. you can add new attributes to chatroom, give edit option on chatroom attribute and it will make your domain model more natural. its not right or wrong, its just good or bad.

Comment: Ok. In that case I will keep the belongs_to and has_many relationship. I guess I am just unsure of how I would query all the messages in a chatroom if I don't explicitly store the chatroom name within a Message model but only store the belongs_to :chatroom relationship. This will automatically store the chatroom_id within the Message model. When I query for the messages in the room action of my chats controller, I use "Message.where(:chatroom_name => @chatroom)." This seems more difficult with ids.

Comment: thanks, its a little bit of complex coding but it will give you benefits later.